# Angular checkbox check

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm writing a code where if a material is approved, it will appear with a blue mark next to it without me checking the checkbox. I tried the method below but, I can still check the box, it does not come already checked. This is what it should look like when the page is opened:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="IsApproved">
                                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ürün Onay Durumu </th>
                                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
                                        <mat-checkbox
                                            [(ngModel)]="row.IsApproved" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                                            binary="true"(onChange)="onChecked($event)"> Approved
                                        </mat-checkbox>
                                    </td>
                                </ng-container>
```

TS Code:

```
export class ManufacturerDetailComponent {
displayedColumns: string[] = [
        "IsApproved",
    ];
    IsApproved: boolean=false;
accept(){
        this.onChecked(true)
       }
   
       onChecked(e: any){
         this.IsApproved = true;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `[checked]` property to show the checked state at start.

```
<mat-checkbox
     [(ngModel)]="row.IsApproved" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
      binary="true"(onChange)="onChecked($event)"
      [checked]="row.IsApproved"> Approved
</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: Nothing really, it stays the same.

Comment: Sorry, but this is the correct way to do it. What happens if you just say `[checked]="true"`. ? I assume that `IsApproved` is false at start.

Comment: Yes, it is false.

Comment: Okay. One more try. Put aside all the parameters and just say `<mat-checkbox [checked]="true">Approved</mat-checkbox>`. Just to demonstrate that it works.

Comment: Okay. can you set `row.IsApproved` to permanently `true`.? Just for the test. And then just structure it this way `<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="row.IsApproved" [checked]="true">Approved</mat-checkbox>`. I'd like to find out whether it the still works.

Comment: Okay. Then add `(onChange)="onChecked($event)"` but leave out  `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" binary="true"`. It should work appropriately now. But  you have to make sure, that `IsApproved` is actually true at start. Otherwise it would be correct, that the tick does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the property `IsApproved` to `true`?

Assuming you have dataSource something like

```
dataSource = [
 {
   "IsApproved": true, //Set this to true so that row.IsApproved will mark the checkbox as checked
   ...
 },
 ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

[(ngModel)] is "Template Forms". It is not supposed to get values, but objects.

Here you have 2 options. Either you make no use of the template forms and use the "value" input property of the checkbox item to set the value like this:

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="row.IsApproved" binary="true (onChange)="onChecked($event)">
 Approved
</mat-checkbox>
```

Or you use the cleanest approach with [(ngModel)] but you have to send an object and not a value.

Comment: ngModel is capable of picking fields out of an object. This is what he does. So there is nothing wrong about this code. But setting the value does not affect the tick. So you're right that he has to use `[checked]`. There is no way around.